# rangelimited x-axis gnuplot disappears

Tags: plot, latex, gnuplot

I am trying to make a figure in gnuplot, similar to the bottom one on [this](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/ellipse.html) page. Specifically, I only want an x- and y-axis on my figure at the places where there is data plotted.

For the y-axis, this works very well using the `ytics rangelimited` option. However, when I use `xtics rangelimited` on the x-axis, the x-axis border disappears:

[image: xtics rangelimited with <code>set border</code> option]

Even more strangely, when I remove the `set border` option, there appears a diagonal line on my graph:

[image: xtics rangelimited without <code>set border</code> option]

The minimal working example to make these figures is:

```
set terminal epslatex standalone size 8.0 cm, 8.0 cm

set output "test.tex"

# Define function
f(x) = abs(x)< 1 ? x**2 : NaN

set border 1+2 front #comment this out to get the diagonal line

set xrange [-1.5:1.5]
set xtics (-1.0,0,1.0) rangelimited nomirror

set yrange [-0.25: 1.25]
set ytics rangelimited nomirror

# plot line
plot f(x) with lines
```

I would like to get for the x-axis a similar result as for the y-axis. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

As a side-question: I would like to have the 0 displayed on the y-axis as well. Is there any automatic way to do this? Or should I always explicitly tell gnuplot to put a tic at 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rangelimited x axis is only drawn to span data points.  You have no data points because you are plotting a function.  In order to have the plot behave as a data plot rather than as a function plot you can use the following convention:

```
plot '+' using 1:(f($1)) with lines
```

See gnuplot documentation for "plot special-filenames"